# Why does touchpad feel different in Wayland?

Tags: 22.04, touchpad

I have `SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad` which feels ok to use in Xorg. But on Wayland it feels different and not as precise. Is there any explanation for that sort of behavior and is there a way to use the same settings for Wayland as on Xorg?

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04.3.